# Rails5 Cameleon CMS - How to define default site

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I followed the [doc](https://github.com/owen2345/camaleon-cms)

```
Start your server

rails server # and then go to your browser http://localhost:3000/
```

the server runs and shows me the gui. but console says:

```
Camaleon CMS - Please define your current site: 
$current_site = CamaleonCms::Site.first.decorate 
or map your domains: 
http://camaleon.tuzitio.com/documentation/category/139779-examples/how.html
```

Not sure where to configure this (which file?)
I tried [this](http://camaleon.tuzitio.com/documentation/category/139779-examples/how.html)

```
# Add an initializer in config/initializers/camaleon_map_sites.rb
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  CamaleonCms::SiteHelper.module_eval do
    def cama_current_site_helper(args)
      if !args[:site].present? && request.present?
        args[:site] =
          CamaleonCms::Site.find_by_slug('localhost:3000').decorate
      end
    end
  end
end
```

..with no success. Any ideas?

Comment: As the comment suggests, you need to create the file config/initializers/camaleon_map_sites.rb and add the above code to it.

Comment: I did but nothing changes

Comment: Did you restart your server?

Comment: yup, I restarted the server, same error

Comment: Same issue @StefHej